# Google workspaceの共有ドライブについて、開発環境と本番環境を用意したい

Tags: google-workspace

現在、システム開発を行っておりまして、その中でGoogle workspaceの共有ドライブ上の共有フォルダの中に「フォルダを作成する」という機能を実装しようとしています。

システム自体は、PHP Laravel,React,MySQLを使用しています。

GoogleDriveであっても開発を行う際は、開発環境と本番環境を分けて用意した方が良いと聞いたのですが、実際に方法はわからず、Googleに問い合わせてみましたが開発のサポートはしていないとの事でした。

実際に開発された事がある方で、開発環境と本番環境の用意をどのようにされたかご教授頂けましたら幸いです。